# Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to lambda, and I am trying to run this code. However, in CloudWatch, I keep on getting this error message.

Here is my code --->

```
import boto3
import print_function

def lambda_handler(event, context):
print ('Init 1Push_Care_DATAprint')
Device_ID_var = event['serialNumber']
print (event)
response = 1Push_Care_USERinfo.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('Device_ID').eq('Device_ID_var'))
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

And here is the error message I keep getting:

> Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax
>   (lambda_function.py, line 9)

The line the error is pertaining to is --->

```
response = 1Push_Care_USERinfo.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('Device_ID').eq('Device_ID_var'))
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with the indentation after your function initiation